# Why is the except statment in menu() getting triggered through normal use of the play() function?

Tags: python

This program is about storing the scores and weather related variables for someone playing a game of archery. The expept statment in menu() is to stop out of bounds inputs from being put into the program, but somehow when i'm using the play() function, when n = 0 the except statment is menu() is getting triggered and I can't understand why. all the functions that are being caled are below.

```
import time, datetime, statistics
from statistics import mean

def storeScore():    
    def Average(list):
        return mean(list)
    global score
    list = []
    list.insert(0, score)
    global average
    average = Average(list)

def Play():
if guest == False:
        n = int(input("Please enter the number of shots you will be firing:"))
        weather = input("Please enter the current weather, excluding wind:")
        wind = input("Please enter the wind conditions:")
        other = input("please enter any other conditions to be recorded:")
    avgscore = 0

    while n > 0:
            print("Please fire your arrow now")
            time.sleep(3)
            global score
            score = int(input("please enter the score for this arrow:"))
            n = n-1
            storeScore()
        myList =[n, weather, wind, other, avgscore]
        with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
            for s in myList:
                f.append(str(s) + '\n')
        print("Thanks you, your data was logged")
        printAvg
        time.sleep(3)
        resetloop()

def menu():
    print("*********************************************\n"
          "*   WELCOME, PLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION        *\n"
          "*                                           *\n"
          "*   1. REGISTER A GUEST                     *\n"
          "*   2. CREATE A FULL DATA EXPORT            *\n"
          "*   3. VIEW YOUR AVERAGE SCORE (50 SHOTS +) *\n"
          "*   4. PLAY A ROUND                         *\n"
          "*   5. CHECK COMPETITION READYNESS          *\n"
          "*   6. EXIT                                 *\n"
          "*********************************************\n")

    Menu_Choice = input("please enter a number from 1-6 for your chosed option:")
    try:
        if Menu_Choice =="1":
            Guest()
        elif Menu_Choice =="2":
            Data_Export()
        elif Menu_Choice =="3":
            Average()
        elif Menu_Choice =="4":
            Play()
        elif Menu_Choice =="5":
            Contest()
        elif Menu_Choice =="6":
            exit()
        else:
            raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print("This is an invalid input, please anter an interger number between 1-6 in number form")
        time.sleep(2)
        resetloop()

def resetloop():
    print(" ")
    menu()
```

Comment: `def Play():
if guest == False:` Bad indentation

Comment: In your code i do not see `if Menu_Choice == "0"` that is why this is getting triggered